# How can I determine if multiples of a duration fit evenly between two dates?

Tags: javascript, typescript, datetime, luxon

I'm using [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/), and have two dates and an [ISO duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations). How can I determine if the duration between the two dates is an multiple of the duration with no remainder?

- 1/23/2000 to 6/23/2000 with P6M returns true
- 1/23/2000 to 1/23/2022 with P6M returns true
- 1/23/2000 to 2/23/2000 with P6M returns false
- 1/23/2000 to 2/23/2022 with P1M returns true
- 1/23/2000 to 2/24/2022 with P1M returns false

I considered converting to "months" for example and just using Javascript's modulus operator to determine if the remainder is 0, but ISO durations can be very complex, eg "P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S" represents a duration of "three years, six months, four days, twelve hours, thirty minutes, and five seconds".

`Interval`s have a [`splitBy`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#intervalsplitby) function that seems promising as it leaves the remainder as the last element in the array it returns, but I'm not sure how to then compare that element to my original duration:

```ts
import {DateTime, Duration, Interval} from 'luxon';

const date1: DateTime = DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date('12/20/2022'));
const date2: DateTime = DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date('12/20/2023'));
const duration: Duration = Duration.fromISO('P6M');

const interval: Interval = Interval.fromDateTimes(date1, date2);
const split = interval.splitBy(duration);
const modulusDuration = (split[split.length - 1] as Interval).toDuration();
if (modulusDuration.valueOf() === duration.valueOf()) {
  console.log('pass'); // We never get here
} else {
  // We get here
  console.log(modulusDuration.rescale().toObject()) // {months: 6, days: 3, hours: 1}
  console.log(duration.rescale().toObject()) // {months: 6}
  console.log('fail');
}
```

Here's a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-kuwjpg?file=index.ts

How can I determine if multiples of a duration fit neatly between two dates?

Comment: You may need to define _exactly_ how ISO durations are interpreted in code, particularly given the length in time of a duration is relative to the start date (month, day of month, leap year etc.), may not be the same time interval when repeated from the end of a duration, and may need interpretation if the end day of month overflows into the next month or year.

Comment: I agree with @traktor. I think the only approach is to iteratively add the duration to the start date using Luxon's [*#plus*](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimeplus) and see if it lands exactly on the end date, counting the number of iterations. PS. A Luxon *duration* can be created from an ISO duration string using [*fromISO*](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#durationfromiso).

Comment: Thank you both, I was able to use your ideas to get this working and have posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @RobG's comment I was able to get this working by iteratively adding the duration to the start date and checking if it lands exactly on the end date:

```ts
import {DateTime, Duration, Interval} from 'luxon';

const date1: DateTime = DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date('1/20/2022'));
const date2: DateTime = DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date('1/20/2023'));
const duration: Duration = Duration.fromISO('P6M');


let pass = false;
for (let i = date1; i <= date2; i = i.plus(duration)) {
  if (i.toMillis() === date2.toMillis()) {
    pass = true;
  }
}
console.log(pass ? 'pass' : 'fail');
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-nodwnx?file=index.ts